# docusaurus fails to find images after build

Tags: build, docusaurus, mdxjs

I have a Docusauris site that works fine when in development mode, served using `npm run start`.  My docs pages (e.g. `docs/GettingStarted.md`) include images such as:

```
<img src="/images/Buttons.png" width="400"/>
```

which are displayed properly when using the development server.

However, if I now run `npm run build` and `npm run serve`, the images are not found.  The build process should have changed the URL to, e.g.  `assets/images/Buttons.png`, but it didn't; it remains unchanged as `/images/Buttons.png`.

It is possible that this arises from a bad `docusaurus.config.js`.  The docusaurus directory is at http://localhost/prsm/doc/help and I am looking at the served pages at http://localhost:3000/prsm/doc/help/

The `docusaurus.config.js` config has the lines:

```
const config = {
  title: 'PRSM',
  tagline: 'Participatory System Mapper',
  url: 'http://localhost',
  baseUrl: '/prsm/doc/help/',
  onBrokenLinks: 'throw',
  onBrokenMarkdownLinks: 'warn',
  favicon: '/images/favicon.ico',
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What I should have done is read the documentation even more closely.  The correct syntax for what I was trying to achieve is:

```
<img src={require("/static/images/Buttons.png").default} width="400"/>
```